# Some apps doesn't sideload into Android 14

Tags: android, app-store, adb

> Starting from Android 14, apps with a targetSdkVersion lower than 23 can't be installed. Requiring apps to meet these minimum target API level requirements improves security and privacy for users [<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#minimum-target-api-level)

App A with targetSdkVersion of 33 - Not able to install

App B with targetSdkVersion of 30 - Able to install

Why is this ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'sideloading'?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to install an app via `adb install` and installation fails?

Comment: @blackapps Install an app to a device with apk

Comment: ??? One always needs an apk. Try without. I have no idea what you do.

Comment: I think Google is tightening the screws because they don't want to support legacy software that doesn't directly work with the runtime permissions system. Keeping their shiny new platforms bloated with such kludges might pose security risks hold and back further development.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rumor has it, Google are planning to offer 7 years of software support for their Pixel phones, starting with the Pixel 8 that comes out this month. I think abandoning legacy apps may be related to this.